# How to access local environment variables in a dbt macro?

Tags: environment-variables, jinja2, dbt

I wonder if there is a way for a `dbt` macro to access local environment variables.

I tried the following syntax, but it didn’t work

```
{{ env.MY_ENV_VARIABLE }}
```

and

```
{{ env_var('MY_ENV_VARIABLE')}}
```

Is there a way to access local variables?

Comment: The below works for me https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/env_var

Answer (score 1):

This syntax worked for me for assigning the environment variable to a local variable.

```
{% set my_env_variable = env_var('MY_ENV_VARIABLE') %}
```

The issues was, that I haven't properly exported the environment variable